# Can we have a factorial of a factorial?

Tags: factorial

Can we have a factorial of a factorial?I tried searching Google but I was unable to find the answer.Please help me.

Comment: Why not? Of course you can have the factorial of the factorial. It is denoted by $(n!)!$.

Comment: But be warned that the parentheses in $(n!)!$ are needed, because $n!!$ unfortunately means something else.

Comment: there was an olympiad (mock i think) on 'super-factorial'

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example $(3!)!$ means $(3\cdot 2\cdot1)!$ which is $6!$, quite large, $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 =720$

They get large very quickly, $(5!)!$ gives an error on a typical calculator and so does $[(3!)!]!$

(Teresa and bof are mentioning that the above should not be confused with !!, which is different and explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial )

Comment: Do mention that the notation for a factorial of a factorial is not $!!$, and it should not be confused with the double factorial. I think this is important since it seems common to confuse both.

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with that one, perhaps you could comment on it

Comment: Read the first line of the Wikipedia article, and the article itself, on the double factorial [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Comment: OK, do you think the answer should be edited with that link included?

Comment: Yes , I feel it should be edited. Your answer is otherwise quite complete. I will add a +1 once I see this edited. (Seen it, +1)